# Insert on array value in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I have a document just like this.

{
    "Node": {
        "-name": "Dev6", 
        "Interface": [
            {
                "-ip": "10.20.18.65", 
                "-mask": "255.255.255.192"
            }, 
            {
                "-ip": "10.20.18.129", 
                "-mask": "255.255.255.192"
            }
        ]
    }
}

My perl program is following.

```
my $dbs_update_Node_by_key ='FOR u IN Node FILTER u._key == @key  UPDATE u WITH {
    name: @name,
    Interface: @Interface
} IN Node';

...... 
(comments: $inf means [{"-ip","-mask"},{"-ip","-mask"}])

my $bind_args = {
key => $doc->{'_key'},
name => $node_attrs->{'-name'},
Interface => $inf
};

$sth = $itdb->query($dbs_update_Node_by_key)->bind($bind_args)->execute();
```

It returns "Invalid bind parameter value". I think ArangoDB perl driver didn't support it.
How can I use AQL or REST API to implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that

```
[{"-ip","-mask"},{"-ip","-mask"}]
```

won't work. When using the curly brackets and member names (e.g. "-ip", "-mask"), there must be a value associated to each member. Using this value instead should work:

```
[{"-ip": "a.b.c.d", "-mask": "a.b.c.d" }, {"-ip": "a.b.c.d" ,"-mask": "a.b.c.d" }]
```

Please also note that in your above query, you will update an attribute named "name", whereas in the example document the attribute name is "-name" (with minus sign in front). To use an attribute name with a minus sign at the beginning, it needs to be quoted in backticks in AQL (see below).

Additionally, the example document has attributes "-name" and "Interface" inside a sub-attribute "Node", whereas the UPDATE command will update attributes "name" and "Interface" on the top level of the document.

I have adjusted the query a bit. The following sequence seems to work from the ArangoShell:

```
db._create("Node"); 
db.Node.save({ 
  "_key": "test", 
  "Node": { 
    "someAttribute": "someValue", 
    "-name": "Dev6",  
    "Interface": [ 
      { 
        "-ip": "10.20.18.65", 
        "-mask": "255.255.255.192" 
      }, 
      { 
        "-ip": "10.20.18.129", 
        "-mask": "255.255.255.192" 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
}); 

dbs_update_Node_by_key = 'FOR u IN Node FILTER u._key == @key ' +
  'UPDATE u WITH { Node: { `-name`: @name, Interface: @Interface } } IN Node'; 

bind_args = { 
  key: "test", 
  name: "Dev8", 
  Interface: [
    {
      "-ip": "8.8.8.8", 
      "-mask": "255.255.255.192" 
    }, 
    {
      "-ip": "192.168.0.1",
      "-mask": "255.255.255.255" 
    }
  ] 
}; 

db._query(dbs_update_Node_by_key, bind_args); 
db.Node.toArray();
```

This will produce:

```
[ 
  { 
    "_id" : "Node/test", 
    "_key" : "test", 
    "_rev" : "18996044030550", 
    "Node" : { 
      "-name" : "Dev8", 
      "someAttribute" : "someValue", 
      "Interface" : [ 
        { 
          "-ip" : "8.8.8.8", 
          "-mask" : "255.255.255.192" 
        }, 
        { 
          "-ip" : "192.168.0.1", 
          "-mask" : "255.255.255.255" 
        } 
      ] 
    } 
  } 
]
```

I am not sure if this is what you required, but at least it updates the document and overwrites the "Interface" attribute with new values.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it according to you advice. BTW, I think "-" isn't suitable for AQL. For example:  'FOR u IN Node FILTER u.-AdminIP == @AdminIP RETURN u' can't be parsed by AQL.

Comment: yes, attribute names starting with a minus sign need to be enclosed in backticks in order to be parsed properly in AQL